# Node<T> with Objects

Tags: java, list, object-oriented-analysis

im a beginner in coding and I got stuck with this question.. My code is very long and its not working. The question is: write a function that will calculate the sum of two polynomials. A polynomial is displayed as (base, exponent). For example:

```
(3,4)(-2,2)(15,0) is 3x^4-2x^2+15.
```

If we have:

```
list1=(11,10)(3,9)(4,7)(20,4)
list2=(8,10)(6,7)(16,1)
list3=list1+list2=(19,10)(3,9)(10,7)(20,4)(16,1)
```

Each list is expressed as Node where the value of each code is (base, exponent). return a new list which is the sum of the two lists.

Here is the object Polynomial:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Polynomial {
private int num1;
private int num2;
public Polynomial(int num1, int num2){
    this.num1=num1;
    this.num2=num2;
}
public int getNum1(){
    return this.num1;
}
public int getNum2(){
    return this.num2;
}
public void setNum1(int num1){
    this.num1=num1;
}
public void setNum2(int num2){
    this.num2=num2;
}
}
```

and the class Node:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Node<T> {
private T value;
private Node<T> next;
public Node(T value){
    this.value=value;
    this.next=null;
}
public Node(T value, Node<T> next){
    this.value=value;
    this.next=next;
}
public T getValue(){
    return this.value;
}
public Node<T> getNext(){
    return this.next;
}
public boolean hasNext(){
    return (this.next!=null);
}
public void setValue(T value){
    this.value=value;
}
public void setNext(Node<T> next){
    this.next=next;
}
public String toString(){
    return value+ " --> " + next;
}
}
```

Now here is the function I wrote (sorry for the length):

```
import java.util.*;
public class q56 {

public static int max(Node<Polynomial> L1, Node<Polynomial> L2){
    int max=0;
    while (L1!=null){
        if (L1.getValue().getNum2()>max){
            max=L1.getValue().getNum2();
        }
        L1=L1.getNext();
    }
    while (L2!=null){
        if (L2.getValue().getNum2()>max){
            max=L2.getValue().getNum2();
        }
        L2=L2.getNext();
    }
    return max;
}

public static int length(Node<Polynomial> L){
    int count=0;
    while (L!=null){
        count++;
        L=L.getNext();
    }
    return count;
}

public static Node<Polynomial> found(Node<Polynomial> L, int max){
    Node<Polynomial> found=null;
    while (L!=null){
        if (L.getValue().getNum2()==max){
            found=L;
        }
        L=L.getNext();
    }
    return found;
}

public static Node<Polynomial> sum(Node<Polynomial> list1, Node<Polynomial> list2){
    Node<Polynomial> listSum=null; Node<Polynomial> posSum=listSum;
    Node<Polynomial> pos1=list1; Node<Polynomial> pos2=list2;
    boolean alreadychecked=false;
        while (pos1!=null){
            while (pos2!=null){
                int max=max(pos1, pos2);
                alreadychecked=false;
                //if the maximum has been found in both of the lists
                if (found(pos1, max)!=null && found(pos2, max)!=null){
                    Node<Polynomial> found1=found(pos1, max);
                    Node<Polynomial> found2=found(pos2, max);
                    Polynomial end=new Polynomial(found1.getValue().getNum1()+found2.getValue().getNum1(), max);
                    if (posSum==null){
                        posSum=new Node<Polynomial>(end);
                        listSum=posSum;
                    }
                    else {
                        posSum.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(end));
                    }
                    //moves to the next one (in list 1)
                    pos1=pos1.getNext();
                    //moves to the next one (in list2)
                    pos2=pos2.getNext();
                    alreadychecked=true;
                }
                //if the maximum has been found in list 1 (and not in list 2)
                else if((found(pos1, max)!=null && found(pos2, max)==null) && alreadychecked==false){
                    if (listSum==null){
                        listSum=found(pos1,max);
                        posSum=listSum;
                    }
                    else {
                        posSum.setNext(found(pos1,max));
                    }
                    //moves to the next one (in list 1)
                    pos1=pos1.getNext();
                    alreadychecked=true;
                }
                //if the maximum has been found in list 2(and not in list1)
                else if((found(pos1,max)==null && found(pos2,max)!=null) && alreadychecked==false){
                    if (posSum==null){
                        posSum=found(pos2,max);
                        listSum=posSum;
                    }
                    else {
                        posSum.setNext(found(pos2,max));
                    }
                    //moves to the next one (in list 2)
                    pos2=pos2.getNext();
                }

            }
        }

    return listSum;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Polynomial one1=new Polynomial(11,11);
    Polynomial one2=new Polynomial(3,9);
    Polynomial one3=new Polynomial(4,7);
    Polynomial one4=new Polynomial(20,4);
    Polynomial one5=new Polynomial(1,2);
    Node<Polynomial> first=new Node<Polynomial>(one1);
    Node<Polynomial> pos1=first;
    Node<Polynomial> list1=first;
    pos1.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(one2));
    pos1=pos1.getNext();
    pos1.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(one3));
    pos1=pos1.getNext();
    pos1.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(one4));
    pos1=pos1.getNext();
    pos1.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(one5));
    while (first!=null){
        System.out.println("("+first.getValue().getNum1()+", "+first.getValue().getNum2()+")");
        first=first.getNext();
    }


    Polynomial second1=new Polynomial(8,10);
    Polynomial second2=new Polynomial(6,7);
    Polynomial second3=new Polynomial(4,2);
    Polynomial second4=new Polynomial(16,2);
    Node<Polynomial> second=new Node<Polynomial>(second1);
    Node<Polynomial> pos2=second;
    Node<Polynomial> list2=second;
    pos2.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(second2));
    pos2=pos2.getNext();
    pos2.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(second3));
    pos2=pos2.getNext();
    pos2.setNext(new Node<Polynomial>(second4));
    System.out.println();
    while (second!=null){
        System.out.println("("+second.getValue().getNum1()+", "+second.getValue().getNum2()+")");
        second=second.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println();

    Node<Polynomial> end=sum(list1, list2);
    while (end!=null){
        System.out.println("("+end.getValue().getNum1()+", "+end.getValue().getNum2()+")");
        end=end.getNext();
    }
}
}
```

Explanation: Each time I scanned both of the lists and found the biggest exponent. Then, I checked if that exponent appears in both of the lists or only one of them. If its in both of the lists then I added the bases and kept the exponent (the maximum). If the maximum is found only in one of the lists, I move that cell to the new list and move to the next cell in the list that the maximum was found. After each if, I move to the next cell in either one of the lists or both of them, and then the whole process starts again with a different maximum. 
I tried the question with these lists:

```
list1=(11,11)(3,9)(4,7)(20,4)(1,2)
list2=(8,10)(6,7)(4,2)(16,2)
```

and all I got back was:

```
(11,11)(16,2)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I can't read your code, so I started writing unit tests to see what it's doing; refactoring as I went.  Here's where I landed.  You should be able to take it from here.  You have to consolidate the merged list into the minimum number of terms.

I renamed your `q56` class `PolynomialUtils`.  I added a toString() method because code repetition is the worst thing a programmer can do.  Here's what I have so far.

Your Node class:

```
package math.badpoly;

/**
 * Node
 * Created by eitanmayer
 * Creation date 1/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695272/nodet-with-objects/34695704#34695704
 */

public class Node<T> {
    private T value;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(T value, Node<T> next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (this.next != null);
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) { return true; }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) { return false; }

        Node<?> node = (Node<?>) o;

        if (!value.equals(node.value)) { return false; }
        return next != null ? next.equals(node.next) : node.next == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = value.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (next != null ? next.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(this.value.toString());
        if (this.next != null) {
            builder.append(this.next.toString());
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Your Polynomial class:

```
package math.badpoly;

/**
 * Polynomial
 * Created by eitanmayer
 * Creation date 1/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695272/nodet-with-objects/34695704#34695704
 */
public class Polynomial {
    private int num1;
    private int num2;

    public Polynomial(int num1, int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public int getNum1() {
        return this.num1;
    }

    public int getNum2() {
        return this.num2;
    }

    public void setNum1(int num1) {
        this.num1 = num1;
    }

    public void setNum2(int num2) {
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) { return true; }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) { return false; }

        Polynomial that = (Polynomial) o;

        if (num1 != that.num1) { return false; }
        return num2 == that.num2;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = num1;
        result = 31 * result + num2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + num1 + "," + num2 + ")";
    }
}
```

Your q56 class renamed to PolynomialUtils with new methods added:

```
package math.badpoly;

/**
 * Created by eitanmayer
 * Creation date 1/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695272/nodet-with-objects/34695704#34695704
 */
public class PolynomialUtils {

    public static int max(Node<Polynomial> list1, Node<Polynomial> list2) {
        return Math.max(maxExponent(list1), maxExponent(list2));
    }

    public static int maxExponent(Node<Polynomial> polynomial) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Node<Polynomial> node = polynomial;
        while (node != null) {
            int exponent = node.getValue().getNum2();
            if (exponent > max) {
                max = exponent;
            }
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static int length(Node<Polynomial> polynomial) {
        int count = 0;
        Node<Polynomial> node = polynomial;
        while (node != null) {
            ++count;
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static Node<Polynomial> found(Node<Polynomial> polynomial, int max) {
        Node<Polynomial> found = null;
        Node<Polynomial> node = polynomial;
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.getValue().getNum2() == max) {
                found = node;
            }
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return found;
    }

    public static Node<Polynomial> last(Node<Polynomial> polynomialNode) {
        Node<Polynomial> last = polynomialNode;
        Node<Polynomial> node = polynomialNode;
        while (node != null) {
            last = node;
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return last;
    }

    public static Node<Polynomial> merge(Node<Polynomial> list1, Node<Polynomial> list2) {
        Node<Polynomial> merged = list1;
        Node<Polynomial> last = PolynomialUtils.last(merged);
        last.setNext(list2);
        return merged;
    }

    public static Node<Polynomial> consolidate(Node<Polynomial> list) {
        // TODO: I've left this for you.
        return null;
    }

    public static Node<Polynomial> sum(Node<Polynomial> list1, Node<Polynomial> list2) {
        Node<Polynomial> listSum = PolynomialUtils.merge(list1, list2);
        return listSum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<Polynomial> list1 =
                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(11, 11),
                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(3, 9),
                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(4, 7),
                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(20, 4),
                                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(1, 2))))));
        System.out.println(list1);

        Node<Polynomial> list2 =
                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(8, 10),
                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(6, 7),
                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(4, 2),
                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(16, 2)))));
        System.out.println(list2);

        Node<Polynomial> sum = sum(list1, list2);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

I wrote Junit tests for the `PolynomialUtils` class:

```
package math.badpoly;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695272/nodet-with-objects/34695704#34695704
 */
public class PolynomialUtilsTest {

    private Node<Polynomial> list1 = createTestPolynomial1();
    private Node<Polynomial> list2 = createTestPolynomial2();


    @Test
    public void testMax() {

        int expected = 11;
        int actual = PolynomialUtils.max(this.list1, this.list2);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLength_List1() {
        Assert.assertEquals(5, PolynomialUtils.length(this.list1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLast_List1() {
        Node<Polynomial> expected = new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(1, 2));
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, PolynomialUtils.last(this.list1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLength_List2() {
        Assert.assertEquals(4, PolynomialUtils.length(this.list2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLast_List2() {
        Node<Polynomial> expected = new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(16, 2));
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, PolynomialUtils.last(this.list2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testFound_Success() {
        Node<Polynomial> expected = new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(11, 11), null);
        Node<Polynomial> actual = PolynomialUtils.found(this.list1, 11);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getValue().getNum1(), actual.getValue().getNum1());
        Assert.assertEquals(expected.getValue().getNum2(), actual.getValue().getNum2());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMerge() {
        Node<Polynomial> expected = createMergedTestPolynomial();
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
        System.out.println(expected);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, PolynomialUtils.merge(this.list1, this.list2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        String expected = "(11,11)(3,9)(4,7)(20,4)(1,2)";
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, this.list1.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        Node<Polynomial> expected = createSumPolynomial();
        Node<Polynomial> x = createTestPolynomial1();
        Node<Polynomial> y = createTestPolynomial2();
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, PolynomialUtils.sum(x, y));
    }


    private Node<Polynomial> createTestPolynomial2() {
        Node<Polynomial> list2 =
                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(8, 10),
                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(6, 7),
                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(4, 2),
                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(16, 2)))));
        return list2;
    }


    private Node<Polynomial> createTestPolynomial1() {
        Node<Polynomial> list1 =
                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(11, 11),
                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(3, 9),
                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(4, 7),
                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(20, 4),
                                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(1, 2))))));
        return list1;
    }

    private Node<Polynomial> createMergedTestPolynomial() {
        Node<Polynomial> mergedList =
                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(11, 11),
                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(3, 9),
                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(4, 7),
                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(20, 4),
                                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(1, 2),
                                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(8, 10),
                                                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(6, 7),
                                                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(4, 2),
                                                                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(16, 2))))))))));
        return mergedList;
    }



    private Node<Polynomial> createSumPolynomial() {
        Node<Polynomial> expectedSum =
                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(11, 11),
                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(8, 10),
                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(3, 9),
                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(10, 7),
                                                new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(20, 4),
                                                        new Node<Polynomial>(new Polynomial(21, 2)
                                                        ))))));
        return expectedSum;
    }
}
```

The tests pass.  All the terms are present in the sum.  You have to consolidate like exponent terms.

I'm not going to answer your question, but I will give some advice that you may find useful today or tomorrow if you decide to continue as a programmer.

1. Write less code.
2. One of the key skills to learn as a developer is
   debugging.
3. Read Bob Martin's [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882).
4. Learn the Java language coding and
   naming standards.  You routinely break them.  It makes your code
   hard to read.
5. Have a look at [JUnit](http://junit.org/) - you'll be glad you did if you continue as a programmer.

I don't think this implementation is optimal.  You've caused a problem by mingling the behavior and list behavior together.  If you decide to change from a linked list you have to rewrite that class.  I think you'll have a better time if they are kept separate.

I'd recommend that you start with a `Monomial` class: it'll encapsulate the coefficient and exponent as private data members.  I think it'd be smart to implement the operations you need (e.g. add, subtract, etc.) on this class.  Make sure that these work perfectly before you proceed.

Once that's written and 100% tested, create a `Polynomial` class.  That will manage a collection of Monomials.  The key idea is that the choice of collection should not be tied up in either `Monomial` or `Polynomial` classes.  You are asked to use linked list.  When you learn about maps and hash tables in the future you might decided that changing from linked list is a very good idea.  You shouldn't have to rewrite either `Monomial` or `Polynomial` on that day.

If I were doing it I'd start with an interface that both `Monomial` and `Polynomial` could implement:

```
package math.polynomial;

/**
 * Interface for simple math operations
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695272/nodet-with-objects/34695704#34695704
 */
public interface SimpleMath <T> {
    T add(T other);
    T sub(T other);
    T mul(T other);
    T div(T divisor);
    T pow(int power);
    T differentiate();
    T integrate();
}
```

I'd code my `Monomial` implementation:

```
package math.polynomial;

/**
 * Monomial class for polynomial
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695272/nodet-with-objects
 */
public class Monomial implements SimpleMath<Monomial> {

    /** Coefficients smaller than this will be considered as zero. */
    public static final double MIN_COEFF = 1.0E-4;

    private double coeff;
    private int expon;

    public Monomial() {
        this(0.0, 0);
    }

    public Monomial(double coeff) {
        this(coeff, 0);
    }

    public Monomial(int expon) {
        this(1.0, expon);
    }

    public Monomial(double coeff, int expon) {
        this.coeff = coeff;
        this.expon = expon;
    }

    public double getCoeff() {
        return coeff;
    }

    public int getExpon() {
        return expon;
    }

    public Monomial add(Monomial other) {
        if (this.getExpon() != other.getExpon()) throw new ExponentMismatchException(this, other);
        return new Monomial(this.getCoeff()+other.getCoeff(), this.getExpon());
    }

    public Monomial sub(Monomial other) {
        if (this.getExpon() != other.getExpon()) throw new ExponentMismatchException(this, other);
        return new Monomial(this.getCoeff()-other.getCoeff(), this.getExpon());
    }

    public Monomial mul(Monomial other) {
        return new Monomial(this.getCoeff()*other.getCoeff(), this.getExpon()+other.getExpon());
    }

    public Monomial div(Monomial other) {
        return new Monomial(this.getCoeff()/other.getCoeff(), this.getExpon()-other.getExpon());
    }

    public Monomial pow(int power) {
        return new Monomial(this.getCoeff(), this.getExpon()*power);
    }

    @Override
    public Monomial differentiate() {
        return (this.getExpon() == 0) ? new Monomial() : new Monomial(this.getCoeff()*this.getExpon(), this.getExpon()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public Monomial integrate() {
        return new Monomial(this.getCoeff()/(this.getExpon()+1), this.getExpon()+1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) { return true; }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) { return false; }

        Monomial other = (Monomial) o;

        return Double.compare(other.coeff, this.coeff) == 0 && this.expon == other.expon;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(coeff);
        result = (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + expon;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%.3f, %d)", this.getCoeff(), this.getExpon());
    }
}
```

I'd unit test it within an inch of its life before proceeding:

```
package math.polynomial;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Junit tests for Monomial
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/9/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695272/nodet-with-objects/34695704#34695704
 */
public class MonomialTest {

    @Test
    public void testContructor_Constant() {
        double testCoeff = 2.0;
        String testString = "(2.000, 0)";
        Monomial monomial = new Monomial(testCoeff);
        Assert.assertEquals(testCoeff, monomial.getCoeff(), Monomial.MIN_COEFF);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, monomial.getExpon());
        Assert.assertEquals(testString, monomial.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructor_UnitCoeff() {
        int testExpon = 2;
        String testString = "(1.000, 2)";
        Monomial monomial = new Monomial(testExpon);
        Assert.assertEquals(1.0, monomial.getCoeff(), Monomial.MIN_COEFF);
        Assert.assertEquals(testExpon, monomial.getExpon());
        Assert.assertEquals(testString, monomial.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructor() {
        double testCoeff = 3.5;
        int testExpon = 2;
        String testString = "(3.500, 2)";
        Monomial monomial = new Monomial(testCoeff, testExpon);
        Assert.assertEquals(testCoeff, monomial.getCoeff(), Monomial.MIN_COEFF);
        Assert.assertEquals(testExpon, monomial.getExpon());
        Assert.assertEquals(testString, monomial.toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(4.0, 4);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(7.0, 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.add(y));
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, y.add(x)); // Addition is commutative
    }

    @Test(expected = ExponentMismatchException.class)
    public void testAdd_ExponentMismatch() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(4.0, 2);
        x.add(y);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd_Identity() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(0.0, x.getExpon());
        Assert.assertEquals(x, x.add(y));  // Zero is the additive identity
        Assert.assertEquals(x, y.add(x));  // Addition is commutative
    }

    @Test
    public void testSub() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(4.0, 4);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(1.0, 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, y.sub(x));
        expected = new Monomial(-1.0, 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.sub(y)); // Subtraction is not commutative
    }

    @Test(expected = ExponentMismatchException.class)
    public void testSub_ExponentMismatch() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(4.0, 2);
        x.sub(y);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMul() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(4.0, 4);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(12.0, 8);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.mul(y));
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, y.mul(x)); // Multiplication is commutative
    }

    @Test
    public void testMul_Identity() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(1.0, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(x, x.mul(y));
        Assert.assertEquals(x, y.mul(x)); // Multiplication is commutative
    }

    @Test
    public void testDiv_ResultOne() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(1.0, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.div(x));
    }


    @Test
    public void testDiv_ResultConstantTerm() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(3.0, 4);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(4.0, 4);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(0.75, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.div(y));
        expected = new Monomial(4.0/3.0, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, y.div(x));  // Division is not commutative
    }

    @Test
    public void testDiv() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(4.0, 4);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(0.5, -1);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.div(y));
        expected = new Monomial(2.0, 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, y.div(x)); // Division is not commutative
    }

    @Test
    public void testDiv_Zero() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial();
        Monomial y = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(0.0, -3);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.div(y));
        expected = new Monomial(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 3);  // Note: No exception is thrown when dividing by 0.0
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, y.div(x));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPow() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(2.0, 6);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.pow(2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPow_ZeroPower_Constant() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(2.0, 0);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.pow(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDifferentiate() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(6.0, 2);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.differentiate());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDifferentiate_Constant() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(4.0);
        Assert.assertEquals(new Monomial(), x.differentiate());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIntegrate() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial expected = new Monomial(0.5, 4);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, x.integrate());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFundamentalTheoremOfCalculus() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Assert.assertEquals(x, x.integrate().differentiate());
        Assert.assertEquals(x, x.differentiate().integrate());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Null() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Assert.assertFalse(x.equals(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Reflexive() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.equals(x));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Symmetric() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.equals(y) && y.equals(x));
        Assert.assertTrue(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Transitive() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial z = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.equals(y) && y.equals(z) && z.equals(x));
        Assert.assertTrue(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
        Assert.assertTrue(y.hashCode() == z.hashCode());
        Assert.assertTrue(z.hashCode() == x.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_DifferentCoefficients_NotEqual() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(1.0, 3);
        Assert.assertFalse(x.equals(y));
        Assert.assertFalse(y.equals(x));
        Assert.assertFalse(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_DifferentExponents_NotEqual() {
        Monomial x = new Monomial(2.0, 3);
        Monomial y = new Monomial(2.0, 4);
        Assert.assertFalse(x.equals(y));
        Assert.assertFalse(y.equals(x));
        Assert.assertFalse(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
    }
}
```

IntelliJ tells me that all my tests pass.  I have 100% test coverage of methods and 75% coverage of lines.

Now that I had `Monomial` working perfectly I'd implement `Polynomial`.  It would use the same interface `SimpleMath<Polynomial>`.  It would choose some collection of `Monomial` that would make the implementation easiest.  This is where you'll find that your choice of data structure will make your life harder or easier.  The good news is that you can change it without bothering clients of your class, because that implementation detail will be hidden inside your class.

Update:

I finished my implementation for `Polynomial`.  It's *surprisingly* subtle.  I'm very glad that I had good Junit tests.  Both `Monomial` and `Polynomial` evolved based on test results.

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed, but his current Polynomial class is actually the Mononomial you recommend. Hard to guess with fields named num1/num2 that's sure.

Comment: I did notice.  That's another confusing bit that I don't like.  Good names matter.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `LinkedList` - which is basically what you implemented with your `Node<T>` class - is going to be a pain in the ass.

You want the sum of two polynomials, that is for each exponent the sum of each's base. For that effect, I would recommend representing the polynomials as `Map<int, int>` where the key is the exponent and the value is the base.

Here are two relevant advantages :

- `map.keySet()` will return the set of the defined exponents of the polynomial.
- `map.get(exponent)` is enough to check the base for an exponent

I would start my algorithm by getting the union of the exponents of the two polynomials. The following should be obvious enough.